# Why won't my on_connect() print the message?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a code that's simple as this

```
bot = discord.Client()

@bot.event
async def on_connect():
    print('Hello!')
```

however, when i run the code it won't print `Hello!` and it doesn't give any error message, and the bot itself did not even turn online
i can't solve it myself since i couldn't find any info online, or it might be that im just dumb ._.

Comment: You need to run the bot, something like `bot.run('token')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `on_connect`, instead, try using `on_ready`

Your code you have provided also seems to refer to the old async version, instead of rewrite, running your bot and defining it should be:
`bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = prefix)`

Your bot also may not be online as you might of missed to actually run your bot via it's token and declaring it.

```
bot.run('token')
```

Also make sure you have imported Discord's modules, otherwise everything should be working. It's best if you start by reading and learning about Discord's documentation guide, as this provides the simple, basic and crucial information in setting up your bot, to avoid these small errors. A guide can be found here:

https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro

```
import discord
import discord.utils
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
```

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Hello!')
```

Comment: ive imported all of discord's modules aswell as declaring my bot token. but i have fixed my code with what you suggested and it worked! thank you so much ^-^